Exporting object with bpy.ops.wm.obj_export()
I'm trying to export a set object with bpy.ops.wm.obj_export() regardless of which objects are selected in the viewport. I tried temporarily overriding the context, but it doesn't seem to work.
C = bpy.context

active = bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']
objects = [bpy.data.objects['Suzanne'],]

with C.temp_override(active_object=active, selected_objects=objects):
    bpy.ops.wm.obj_export(filepath=export_path, export_selected_objects=True)

Whatever is overridden it seems to get ignored and the objects selected in the viewport are always exported. Does anyone have an idea on why it doesn't work?

bpy.ops.wm.obj_export(export_selected_objects=True) ?
